# Magento - How to add a custom render to a custom column in the orders grid?

Tags: magento, render, adminhtml

For a Magento website, I would like to show custom options in the orders grid in the backoffice.

Currently, I've successfully added a custom column to the grid with the help of [this guide](http://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/) and [this guide](http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-sku-column-to-orders-grid/), using a module to avoid to rewrite the core classes.

Now, I've a long string appearing in a column and I would like to serialize it to have the custom options, but I can't manage to use a custom renderer.

/app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Helper/Data.php :

```
public function getProductOptionsColumnParams()
{
    return array(
        'header' => 'Products Options',
        'index' => 'product_options',
        'type' => 'text',
        'renderer' => array('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer', 'render'),
    );
}
```

I've added a renderer which links to the Model Observer (/app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Model/Observer.php), but this doesn't work, it only shows a white page instead of the table...

Where did I do a mistake ? The "render" function cannot be in the Observer ? I tried to create a class which extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract in /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order (near to Grid.php) but it doesn't work either.

UPDATE 1 :

It doesn't work, I've created the file `/app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Block/Adminhtml/ExtendedGrid/Renderer/Renderer.php` with the code :

```
class Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Block_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        return '<span style="color:red;">'.$value.'</span>';
    }
}
```

And in /app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Helper/Data.php I have this code :

```
class Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * parameters for addColumnAfter method
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSkusColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'SKUs',
            'index' => 'skus',
            'type' => 'text',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer', 'filterSkus'),
        );
    }
    /**
     * parameters for addColumnAfter method
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProductOptionsColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'Products Options',
            'index' => 'product_options',
            'type' => 'text',
            'renderer' => array('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Block_Product', 'render'),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a renderer doing? Is there a explanation somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

I used a way easier approach to the color. 
first I override the core grid on my local folder:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

Then I added my custom column and added the renderer attribute to it.

```
       $this->addColumn('fee_amount', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Amount to be Paid Later'),
        'index' => 'fee_amount',
        'filter_index'=>'fee_amount',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        'width' => '80px',
        'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Red',

    ));
```

Then create Red.php under

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Renderer/Red.php
```

On red.php i added the following:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Red extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
      public function render(Varien_Object $row)
      {
          $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());

               return '<div style="color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;background:#F55804;border-radius:8px;width: 40%;margin-left: 40px;">$'.number_format( $value , 2).'</div>';


      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `renderer`

```
public function getProductOptionsColumnParams()
    {
        return array(
            'header' => 'Products Options',
            'index' => 'product_options',
            'type' => 'text',
            'renderer' => 'Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Block_Product',
        );
    }
```

Comment: I still have a blank table. It strange that I've no error appearing ! I've however activated the error display...

Comment: just want to add: magento class naming conventions can and should be used here as usual. for blocks it could be 'renderer' => 'atwix_extendedgrid/product'

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your custom  render file at `Package_Name/Module_Name/Block/Adminhtml/Module_Name/Renderer/Renderer.php`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work, I've updated my question to show you what I've done.